# curl --data-urlencode UTF-8

Tags: java, curl, utf-8, get

I would like to send a HTTP GET request that contains a json as a parameter. The server expects the parameter to be encoded with UTF-8.

```
curl -G -v "http://localhost:8000/job" --data-urlencode "request={"clientId"="13","message"="I want apples"}"
```

I have used `--data-urlencode` but it doesn't seam to encode in UTF-8 because the server cannot decode the request.

I have a java client that uses

```
String charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
String requestParameter = request={"clientId":"13","message"="I want apples"}
URLEncoder.encode(requestParameter, charset)
```

to encode the parameter and then send the HTTP GET request and the server accepts the request and is able to decode correctly.

The correct curl command is:

```
curl -G -v "http://localhost:8000/job" --data-urlencode 'request={"clientId":"13","messave":"I want apples"}'
```

Comment: You are running `curl` from a bash command line, I assume. Then you should mind your quotes. Use a single quote around the whole text if you want double quotes inside it.

Comment: Yes, i use `curl` from a bash. I have changed the " with ' and the request looks like this 
`curl -G -v "http://localhost:8000/job" --data-urlencode 'request={"clientId"="13","message"="I want apples"}'` 
but the server is still not able to decode correctly the parameter.

Comment: Those should be `:` rather than `=` characters inside the string, shouldn't they?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yes, you are right, I tried so many variants and messed up the json. Everything works ok after changing `=` with `:` in the json.